# Css Grid landing page

Tags: html, css

I'm design a landing page. in my top container i have an image, Header text and a countdown timer.

Im struggling to make it responsive. Below is a picture of my desired outcome. as well as the code snippets i have came up with so far.

[image]

Index.html

```
<div class="top-container">

    <div class="header">
        <img src="images/fortytrans.png" style="height:600px; width:300px;">
    </div>



    <div class="timer">

        <section class="landing">
            <div class="landing-inner">
                <div class="countdown"></div>
            </div>
        </section>

        <script src="clock.js"></script>

    </div>

    <div class="image">
        <img src="images/mainguy.png" style="height:600px; width:300px;">

    </div>


  </div>
```

main.css

```
    .top-container{
        grid-area: content;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-areas: 
        "header"
        "timer"
        "image"
           ;
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      grid-template-rows: 130px 800px 250px;
      }

  .header{
     grid-area: header;
 }

   .timer{
    grid-area: timer;
 }

 .image{
    grid-area: image;
}
```

Comment: Use two different images , one in the side and one in the middle of the two divs, then set property display (none, or block) in media query to show hide the images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're over complicating things. You don't need a grid for a simple one-column linear view. Take it out for the mobile view.

Then just add a grid with a media query for the wider layout.

```css
header,
section,
div {
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 1em;
  background: #aaa;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  body {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "image header" "image timer";
  }
  div {
    grid-area: image;
  }
  header {
    grid-area: header;
  }
  section {
    grid-area: timer;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  Header
</header>
<section>
  Timer
</section>
<div>
  Image
</div>
```